# Verify Azure OAuth token in Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, jwt

I would like to verify an OAuth JWT token granted from Azure to a React app. After some research, this is how I understood it should be implemented:

```
const getSigningKeys: jwt.GetPublicKeyOrSecret = (header, callback) => {
  const _client = jwksClient({
    jwksUri: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/discovery/v2.0/keys`,
  });
  _client.getSigningKey(header.kid, (err: any, key: any) => {
    const signingKey = key?.publicKey || key?.rsaPublicKey;
    callback(null, signingKey);
  });
};

export const verifyMicrosoftToken = async (tokenId: string): Promise<any> => {
  const validationOptions = {
    audience: CLIENT_ID, // v2.0 token
    iss: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/v2.0`, // v2.0 token
    algorithms: ['RS256' as Algorithm],
  };

  const decodedToken = await promisify(jwt.verify)(
    tokenId,
    getSigningKeys,
    validationOptions
  );

  return decodedToken;
};
```

Am I missing anything here? I keep getting the following error:

```
JsonWebTokenError: secret or public key must be provided
```

Answer (score 0):

This error could be due to getSigningKeys not returning a public key. You should check the value of signingKey that's being passed to the callback method. If key is undefined, then signingKey will be undefined, which will result in the JWT error. You can also directly invoke the key.getPublicKey() function.

```
  client.getSigningKey(header.kid, (err, key: jwksClient.SigningKey) => {
    const signingKey = key.getPublicKey()
    callback(null, signingKey)
  })
```